# Decode encoded string while transforming in openidm

Tags: forgerock, openidm

I want to decode the string while transforming the data from Active Directory to OpenIDM. Sync between the system is alright but one of the attribute have base64 encoded string.

I want to transform the property before persisting it into managed user object.

Anyone have any idea how can I achieve it. I tried few javascript ways but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to achieve the decoding of the string using below transformation

```
if (source != null)
{
    var base64 = Packages.org.forgerock.util.encode.Base64url
    b64tO = new Packages.java.lang.String(base64.decode(source));
    logger.info("Decoded: {}", b64tO);
    target = b64tO;
}
```

Hope it help someone !!!